# What are these insects I believe are eating my hydrangea leaves and how can I treat them?

Tags: identification

What are these insects I believe are eating the leaves of my hydrangeas?                               [image][image]

Answer (score 5):

Looks to me like an insect [of the order Dermaptera](https://www.orkin.com/other/earwigs/) ([earwig](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=earwig+images&client=firefox-b&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR6_ik0_TTAhVDOMAKHazOCowQsAQIJg&biw=911&bih=394)):

[image: Forficula auricularia]
(*Forficula auricularia*)

They like water and so do hydrangeas. Advice of how to deal with them at: [Rodale's Organic Life](https://www.rodalesorganiclife.com/garden/how-to-control-earwigs).

Basically, clear away damp hidey-holes from where you do not want the earwigs  and add traps (eg moist newspaper, fish oil in sunken cans) to gather them together for ease of relocation (they are not without benefit to a garden), or disposal.